# OpenCV installation

Tags: opencv

In file included from /home/lucas/OpenCV/opencv-3.2.0/modules/core/src/hal_internal.cpp:49:0:
/home/lucas/OpenCV/build/opencv_lapack.h:2:45: fatal error: LAPACKE_H_PATH-NOTFOUND/lapacke.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/build.make:906: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/hal_internal.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/hal_internal.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1945: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

I believe this is because my python path is set incorrectly...

Answer (score 1):

- install package liblapacke-dev
- manually define -DLAPACKE_H_PATH=/usr/include when calling cmake